# how to use dataframe column headers as row value in a single column, and aggregate multiple column values into one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, multiple-columns

i am looking for some help on how to format a pandas dataframe

input

```
date         A     B
8/1/2022   $100  $50
```

desired output

```
date        type   amount
8/1/2022     $A     $100
8/1/2022     $B      $50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). Your identifier column is `date`.

try:

```py
df = df.melt(id_vars=["date"], 
        var_name="type", 
        value_name="amount")
```